# Swapping contents in Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html

I am using drag and drop so that students can take pieces of a jumbled up image and drop them on to a grid to recompose the original image.

Both grids (jumbled up and reconstruction) allow for dropping, and everything works fine.

However, there might be cases where a student drops one object on top of another, and I want to have the code move the original object to the one recently vacated by the selected item.

I have experimented with different concepts and might be going down the wrong route but used the following for testing:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var tgt = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var currentContents = document.getElementById(tgt);
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(tgt));
    var newContents = document.getElementById(tgt);
    alert("Current = " + currentContents + " - New = " + newContents);

}
```

The idea here was that I could simply store the element details itself, or the innerHTML into a variable, allow the drop to happen as it would normally, then assign the captured HTML to the previous div.

However, the code above only reports [object HTMLimageElement] (even though, in this case, the recipient does not contain any image data).

I tried innerHTML but simply received nothing at all.

And I haven't even begun to work out how to identify the original div that the dragged image came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, spent some time exploring all of the values I could make sense of.

I ended up with this:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var prntId = ev.target.parentNode.id;
    var tgt = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var tgtId = ev.target.id;

    if (prntId === "targetDiv") {
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(tgt));
        imgPos[searchList(tgt)] = tgtId;
    } else {
        var thought = document.getElementById(prntId);
        var orgHTML = thought.innerHTML;
        var listPos = imgPos[searchList(tgt)];
        thought.removeChild(thought.firstChild);
        thought.appendChild(document.getElementById(tgt));
        document.getElementById(listPos).innerHTML = orgHTML;
        imgPos[searchList(tgtId)] = listPos;
        imgPos[searchList(tgt)] = prntId;
    }
}

function searchList(searchItem) {for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {if (imgId[i] === searchItem) {return i;}}}
```

Not the most beautiful piece of code I have written but functional.

I identified that when the DIV was empty, the ID being returned was the DIV's ID, yet when a child was added, the ID being returned was of the image ID. I could get the HTML img tag in its entirety, so I had everything I need.

Basically, if there is no child element to the DIV, the event target.parentNode.id returns "targetDiv". I, therefore, append a child to the DIV (ID returned by the stored data in dataTransfer), and update the image list with its new position.

However, any other value is the ID of the parent DIV. I, therefore, copy the current HTML in the target DIV into a variable (orgHTML), locate the original position that the tgt image has been dragged from, place the orgHTML data in this, now vacated, DIV.

I then continue with the drop part of the process, once I have removed any children from the DIV, updating the new position of the image within the relevant list.

That is as clear as mud (I am tired and it is late), but it might help someone, one day. :)